# mystery first value appearing out of nowhere

Tags: r, for-loop

Running simple code to read through many files at the same time and extracting data and collecting the means. The first value extracted is wrong (0), I've checked the data manually and the first data point to be extracted would be 7.21 (the 2nd value), i cant seem to figure out where the first is being generated from.

Ive tried going over it manually but seems to be something wrong with my code.

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, id = 1:332){
results <- vector('numeric', 1)
for (i in id){
if(i < 10){
path <- paste(directory, '/00', i, '.csv', sep = '')
data <- read.csv(path)
mn <- na.omit(data[[pollutant]])
results<- c(results, mn)
}
```

When i plug in the first 2 arguments and 1:10 (meaning the first 10 files) I get 11 results.

[1]  0.0000  7.2100  5.9900  4.6800  3.4700  2.4200  1.4300  2.7600  3.4100  1.3000  3.1500

The first value is unexpected and I dont know where its coming from. Its throwing my mean off.
Can someone please help? Thank you

Comment: You initialize the vector results with length 1. At the end of your function you add to the results vector the value nm. This you do ten times so you get a vector of length 11 as the initial results vector has alreadylength 1.

Comment: @kath, please post your comment as an answer ... (although I could also see closing this as only slightly above the level of a typo ...)

Comment: I can write up an answer, but I don't see how this could help others in the future...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your function you first initialize the vector results:

```
results <- vector('numeric', 1)
```

This creates a vector of length 1 with 0 as entry:

```
results
# [1] 0
```

Now, inside your `for`-loop after reading in the data and everything you apend your result `nm` to the `results` vector. To visualize this I set the result to be the id for each step.

```
for (i in 1:10){
  mn <- i
  results <- c(results, mn)
}
```

So in each step of your loop we add an entry to the vector results, which initially has already length 1.

```
results
# [1]  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Fixed the issue immediately! :)